# Need to wait after WifiManager.reconnect()

Tags: android, wifimanager

I use the WifiManager to connect a specific application to a specific Wifi SSID.
I encounter a strange problem but as it seems I'm the only one to get this problem, I wonder if it's because I test it on a genymotion emulator....

The problem is simple, it works in debug and not in normal run.

In fact the call to responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode(); 
the part of the code is this one:

```
            ....
            List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
            for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
                if(i.SSID != null && (i.SSID.equals("\"" + site.getWifiSSID() + "\"") == false)) {

                     wifi.disconnect();
                     wifi.enableNetwork(conf.networkId, true);
                     wifi.reconnect();               

                     break;
                 }
             }
             String verif = site.getWifiSSID();
             // I tried this but the wifi is enabled in fact. It just seems to be not ready
             for (int i = 0; (wifi.getWifiState() != WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) && i < 300; i++) {
                 try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                 } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.d("2ndGuide", "InterruptException" + e);
                 }
             }
        }

        try {
            int responseCode = 0, i = 0;
            url = new URL(site.getDescriptionFileUrl());

            // Here is the stupid code I need to add to get it working!!!
            try {   
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d("2ndGuide", "InterruptException" + e);
            }
            // Création d'une connection HTTP à une URL
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
            responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                 ...
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d("2ndGuide", "Malformed URL Exception." + e);

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("2ndGuide", "IO Exception." + e);
        }
        // The call to getRespnseCode() exits here with a return value of 0
        Log.d("2ndGuide", mActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.label_messageAlertCnfBadUrl));
        return -6;
```

It seems that the wifi is not immediately ready to be used after a call to reconnect().

So why not, but I didn't find any warning about it and any mechanism to wait until it can be used!
there is certainly something I miss!

Regards,
Alain

Comment: I don't have any deep insight into any of this, but I wanted to say that I too found that I had to add a delay after the reconnect() call, so you're not alone!